# Post on Facebook fan page as an application not user

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

i am using this to post on page or user profile :

```
      var fb = new FacebookOAuthClient(FacebookApplication.Current);
                dynamic resultt = fb.GetApplicationAccessToken();
                var appAccessToken = resultt.access_token;
                dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
                messagePost.access_token = appAccessToken;
                messagePost.picture = "http://www.destination360.com/europe/sweden/images/s/sweden-visby.jpg";
                messagePost.link = "http://www.destination360.com/europe/sweden/images/s/sweden-visby.jpg";
                messagePost.name = "[SOME_NAME]";
messagePost.from = "[SOME_Id]";
messagePost.to = "[SOME_Id]";
                messagePost.caption = "{*actor*} " + "[YOUR_MESSAGE]"; //<---{*actor*} is the user (i.e.: Aaron)
                messagePost.description = "[SOME_DESCRIPTION]";

                FacebookClient appp = new FacebookClient(appAccessToken);

                    var result = appp.Post("/" + appId + "/feed", messagePost);
                    var result2 = appp.Post("/" + "130736200342432" + "/feed", messagePost);
```

well when i try to post on page as an application it gives me this error :

```
(OAuthException) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

Comment: it is only give me the chance to post on user profile not page and i tried to put from and to property the same

Comment: Hi Eslam, did you solved it? I also have to post at wall from my application, but get the same OAuthException.

Comment: not yet ,because the requirements of my project was changed ,so i ignore it for now until i finish my task sheet but i am trying to find a solution for it ,friend of me told me do it using javascript sdk it will be easier ,as soon as i find an answer i will post  it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some thing i figured out when you dealing with the application within facebook fan page you deal with it as a user and the same when you deal with it within the user profile you can publish on fanpage as a user not as an application and you can publish on the user wall as an application and as user the idea is you ask form user permission not for page permission which men you ask the user to give you permission on his own page soo the user have to log in and use you application and in your first action just post the message on the wall but if you are not owner of the page it will fire an exception i am sure if  i am  wrong any one correct me :)

you can use :

```
messagePost.from = "[SOME_Id]";
messagePost.to = "[SOME_Id]";
```

but this did not do any thing different with me ,so any one knows how to post in the wright way please share your experience or some suggestions .

thanks.

Comment: It is not working as i thought it is going to work I change in some thing else but i do not remember what it was i will post it ,oh yes i post using javascript sdk :)